# Am I blocked in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have the following problem in Facebook:

When I'm logged in with my account, a person’s profile appears as "Page not available" with a broken like logo.

When I'm not logged in or when I'm with another account, I can see that person's profile perfectly.

Am I blocked so they appear as if they didn't exist only to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, She/He has blocked you. But generally, if somebody has blocked you, the page will redirect to your own homepage.

Comment: Redirection usually happens when the profile is deactivated for some reason.